# ParseJson Error Roku

Tags: video-streaming, roku, brightscript

I am parsing JSON data. I am using Roku OS 7.0

my code :

```
if (code = 200)
json = ParseJSON(msg.GetString())
```

But it throws "ParseJson:Unknown Identifier Error". How can I solve this?

Comment: What's in msg.getString()? Print it to console first, seems parseJSON does not like the string

Answer (score 1):

Just try to print the string got by msg.GetString() and try with some JSON validator.

For Sure you don't have proper JSON string in your ParseJSON function argument.

Also, make sure use of invalid check for any data got from the server to avoid app crash in Roku.